# Azure Start/Stop VM via webhook

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

We have multiple VM's in our azure environment with multiple resourcegroups. Some of the resourcegroups have multiple VM's. We are now using an URL triggers webhook that will start or stop VM's. This is working, but when a resourcegroup contains multiple VM's all the VM's will start or all the VM's will stop instead of the one you want to start/stop.

Tried multiple scripts but it's isn't working or give me errors.

```
    param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
  [object] 
  $WebHookData
 )  

write output "Data WebHook $WebHookData"

#retrieve ResourceGroup
$ResourceGroupName = $WebHookData.RequestBody
write output "Data ResourceGroup $ResourceGroupName"

$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
Connect-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Conn.TenantID -ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint

$VMs = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName

    if(!$VMs) 
    {
        Write-Output -InputObject 'No VMs were found in the specified Resource Group.'
    }
    else 
    {
        ForEach ($VM in $VMs) 
        {
            $StartVM = Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $VM.Name -Force #-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue


        } 
    } 

$message = ConvertTo-Json -Compress -InputObject ([ordered]@{
       headers = @{'content-type' = 'text/plain'}
          body = ''
    statusCode = 200
})
```

Comment: What error do you get? And you just stop all the VMs in the group according to the script.

Comment: true this script is doing all the VM's in one resourcegroup, but there is a need to do only a specified vm in the resourcegroup. So i created a logicapp with a webhook that is doing /ResouceGroup{ResourceGroup}/VMName{VMName}, and is creating the URL for it. That is also doing fine. But then the script needs to pick that up, and tried several things but not the correct one i guess :) I must admit that im not that good in this coding stuff, and it's a little trial and error now.

Comment: So what is the error? Or what stoped you?

Comment: As @CharlesXu mentions the script you posted will stop all VMs in the resource group.  Your ForEach loop does not contain any condition to determine if the VM should be stopped, it just stops it.

Comment: @Marc-FlorianvanBrakel If my answer was helpful you can mark it as answer to help other. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try below script for ***Start/Stop*** Virtual machine.

**Start VM**

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
$servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName
$null = Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint
$VMs = Get-AzureRmResource|Where-Object {$_.Tags.Keys -eq "owner" -and $_.Tags.Values -eq "daneum"}
foreach ($VM in $VMs) {
    if ($VM.ResourceType -eq "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines") {
        Start-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $VM.ResourceGroupName -Name $VM.Name -Verbose
    }
}
```

**Stop VM**

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
$servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName
$null = Add-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint
$VMs = Get-AzureRmResource|Where-Object {$_.Tags.Keys -eq "owner" -and $_.Tags.Values -eq "daneum"}
foreach ($VM in $VMs) {
    if ($VM.ResourceType -eq "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines") {
        Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $VM.ResourceGroupName -Name $VM.Name -Force -Verbose
    }
}
```

For webhook integration procedure you could take a look [here](https://www.danielstechblog.io/start-and-stop-azure-vms-without-access-to-microsoft-azure/)

Comment: Hi Md Farid, I will try it this week. Was a week out of the office. Thanks in advance.